# How plotting function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to graph , round courner (like black line)
[image]

Comment: How are you creating the plot in the image?

Comment: Do you know this function?

Comment: I am plotting this graphe by geogebra

Comment: As Zarko asks, do you know the function that's generating it? [Geogebra has TikZ export options](https://www.geogebra.org/wiki/en/Export_to_LaTeX_(PGF,_PSTricks)_and_Asymptote), but perhaps there is a more direct route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `..controls(A)and(B)..`  to control the curvature  of line 
here we can use four points (see picture)

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

% draw axis
\draw[->,thick](0,-2.2)--(0,4.7);
\draw[->,thick](-7,0)--(7,0);

% draw ticks
\foreach \i in{-6,-5,...,6}{\draw(\i,0)--(\i,-0.1);}
\foreach \i in{-6.5,-5.5,...,7.5}{\draw(\i,0)--(\i,-0.05);}
\foreach \j in{-2,-1,...,4}{\draw(0,\j)--(-0.1,\j);}
\foreach \j in{-1.5,-0.5,...,4.5}{\draw(0,\j)--(-0.05,\j);}

% draw red lines
\draw[red,thick](-2,-2.2)--(-2,4.7);
\draw[red,thick](2,-2.2)--(2,4.7);
\node[below left,red]  at (2,0) {\scriptsize $\beta$};
\node[below right,red] at (-2,0){\scriptsize $-\beta$};

% draw function and node near plot 
\draw[blue,very thick](-7,-1.5)..controls(-2,-1.5)and(-3.4,-0.3)..(-2,0)--(2,0)..controls(3.4,0.3)and(2,1.5)..(7,1.5)node[pos=0.65,above]{\scriptsize $\varphi_{\gamma,\beta}(\sigma)$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]